# Tell ffserver which track to use

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I want to stream videos via ffserver. My videos are in container formats like mkv and avi and sometimes have multiple audio/video tracks. How can I tell ffserver which track to use? It seems to always take the first one.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [this page](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Streaming%20media%20with%20ffserver) they show this technique of using ffmpeg to do the slicing and then having it forward it to the ffserver:

```
$ ffmpeg \
    -f v4l2 -s 320x240 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 \
    -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:0 \
    http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
```

The above command is doing the following:

- The first part `-f v4l2 -s 320x240 -r 25 -i /dev/video0` represents the first input for `ffmpeg` and captures our webcam video. For more info, you can read more about How to capture a webcam input.
- The second part `-f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:0` represents the second input for `ffmpeg` and captures our audio, depending on our system audio configuration. For more info, you can read more about Capturing audio with FFmpeg and ALSA.
- The last, but not the least important, part `http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm` represents the feed URL, which tells ffmpeg to connect to ffserver and send it the audio + video streams for broadcast. In this example we used the hostname `localhost` which means that everything is running on our computer, but if you need to feed the live online ffserver, you'll need to change the `localhost` to the real host name or IP address of your ffserver computer. Also make sure that your feed name ends with `.ffm` and if it's not the case, then add `-f ffm` before your feed URL, to manually specify the output format (because `ffmpeg` won't be able to figure it out automatically any more), like this `-f ffm http://localhost:8090/blah.bleh`.

As soon as you type the command above, you should see ffmpeg displaying some statistics about your input streams and counting output frames, which is a pretty good sign that everything works (so far).

Comment: thanks that would be a work around which I could use. The downside is that I would have a running process for every possible video file. I hoped there would be a simple option for the stream setting inside the ffserver.conf.

Comment: Yeah I didn't see a way to do that.